# How to use onPress with a Flatlist

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am trying to build a `FlatList` in react native. The problem i am having is with the `onPress` prop and trying to get it to work with the `FlatList`. The problem is that the onPress will be hit for every single item in the list instead of the ones that I specifically press on.

This is the `Flatlist` in my component:

```py
           <FlatList
              data = {this.state.dataSource}
              renderItem = {({item}) => <PickerBox title = {item.c_syn_name} onPress = {this._onPress(item.c_syn_name)} />}
              keyExtractor = {(item, index)=> item.c_syn_name}
              backgroundColor = "thistle"

            />
```

This is the `PickerBox` component:

```py
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      container: {
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: "row",
        padding: 10,
        marginLeft: 16,
        marginRight: 16,
        marginTop: 8,
        marginBottom: 8,
        borderRadius: 5,
        backgroundColor: "slategrey",
        elevation: 2
      },
      shadow: {
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: "row",
        padding: 0,
        marginLeft: 16,
        marginRight: 16,
        marginTop: 8,
        marginBottom: 8,
        borderRadius: 5,
        backgroundColor: "darkslategray",
        elevation: 2
      },
      title: {
        fontSize: 16,
        color: "#000"
      },
      container_text: {
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: "column",
        marginLeft: 12,
        color: "#FFF"
      },
      description: {
        fontSize: 11,
        fontStyle: "italic"
      }
    });

    class PickerBox extends Component<props> {
      render() {
        const { title } = this.props;
        return (
          <View style={styles.shadow}>
            <View style={styles.container}>
              <Text
                style={styles.container_text}
                onPress={() => this.props.onPress}
              >
                {title}
              </Text>
            </View>
          </View>
        );
      }
    }
    export default PickerBox;
```

This is my `onPress` function, it is located in the component that contains my flatlist and is passes via `props` in the `PickerBox` function:

```py
    _onPress = newName => {
        this.setState({ newTaxon: newName });
        Alert.alert("New Taxon: "+this.state.newTaxon.toString());
    };
```

The behavior is that the `Alert` will come up for every list item, while it should only come up for the items that I specifically press.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are invoking your `onPress` callback immediately in `renderItem` on this line:

```
onPress = {this._onPress(item.c_syn_name)}
```

which means that `onPress` gets the result of `_onPress`. This is why you are getting that alert popup every time. You need to give `onPress` the function to invoke. A simple way to give that is to do something like this:

```
onPress={() => this._onPress(item.c_syn_name)}
```

By wrapping it in an arrow function, `_onPress` is not immediately invoked when the `FlatList` is rendered. The value `_onPress` has now is a function for it to invoke.

Answer (score 1):

```
const Main = () => {
    <FlatList
       data={[
          {id: 1, title: one},
          {id: 2, title: two}
         ]}
       keyExtractor={(item) => item.id.toString()}
       renderItem={({item}) => (
          <Card 
           onPress={() => yourFunction()}
           title={item.label}
          />
        }
     />
 }



const Card = ({ onPress, title }) => {
    <View onPress={onPress}>
      <Text>{title}</Text>
    </View>
}
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing an answer. Would you kindly edit your answer to to include an explanation of your code? That will help future readers better understand what is going on, and especially those members of the community who are new to the language and struggling to understand the concepts.